# How to enable/disable the finish button on the IDEA's wizard?

Tags: swing, intellij-idea

I noticed that the method `getFinishButton()` in the class `com.intellij.ide.wizard.AbstractWizard`, from the Intellij IDEA Open API, is deprecated. But there is no comment on the method and I couldn't find any documentation. What I need to do is just enable/disable the button. So, any method for doing this (even of not accessing the object directly) is fine. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finish** button is available only on the last step of the wizard, so you should use `getNextButton()` on the final step to get this button.

There was a [refactoring to remove the separate Finish button](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/8eaff5cd05faf005879ffa5d6b0d39cd5a784ddc) and now **Next** button [becomes](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/ide/wizard/AbstractWizard.java#L457) **Finish** button on the last step.

`getFinishButton()` must not be used as it's just a stub:

```
  protected JButton getFinishButton() {
    return new JButton();
  }
```

To disable the **Finish** button override the `canGoNext()` method and return `false` when needed (or override `canFinish()` instead).